# in calculator if operator is wrong it should ask only for operator

Tags: c++, calculator

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int a,b;
char op;
op=('+','-','/','*');


cout<<"enter first number\n ";
cin>>a;

cout<<"enter second number\n ";
cin>>b;

cout<<"enter operator\n ";
cin>>op;
double result=0.0;

if(op == '+'){
cout<<a+b;

}else if(op == '-'){
cout<<a-b;

}else if(op == '/'){
cout<<a/b;

}else if(op =='*'){
cout<<a*b;

}while(op!='+','-','/','*'){

    cout<<"wrong operator\n ";
    cin>>op;
    
    return result;

}
}
```

i have created this calculator but when user input invalid operator it should ask again only for operator
what should i do
so that it only ask for operator not for numbers again

Answer (score -1):

You must enter the part of the code that is related to receiving the operator from the user in the loop.
The loop must continue until the user enters the operator correctly.

```
 cout<<"enter operator\n";
 cin>>op;
 while(op!='+','-','/','*'){
    cout<<"wrong operator\n ";
    cin>>op;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer may be improved by including a specific code example.

Comment: How many times do you want to keep on asking?